# Replace com Fragment não funciona corretamente

Tags: android

Estou fazendo um exemplo simples com *fragments* e o que preciso é que quando clicar no primeiro botão o app faça o *replace* para Fragmen1 e quando clicar no segundo botão apareça o Fragment2.

Quando inicio a aplicação o fragment que deixei setado no XML aparece normalmente, mas o problema acontece quando eu clico em qualquer um dos botões para substituir um *fragment*, aí acontece isso:

[image: Início da aplicação]

[image: Depois que clico no botão 1]

O que acontece é que o *fragment* que estava no início não desaparece, simplesmente fica na parte de cima do espaço reservado para os *fragments*.

Seguem os XMLs e Classes:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button btn1, btn2;
FragmentManager fm;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFrag1);
    btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFrag2);

    fm = getFragmentManager();

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Fragmento1 f1 = new Fragmento1();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentPlace,f1);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });

    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Fragmento2 f2 = new Fragmento2();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentPlace,f2);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });
}

public class Fragmento1 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1,container,false);
    }
}



public class Fragmento2 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_2,container,false);
    }
}
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnFrag1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fragment 1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnFrag2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fragment 2"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentPlace"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.example.dideconto.exemplofragmentsimples.Fragmento2"></fragment>
</LinearLayout>
```

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Fragmento 2"/>
```

Gostaria de saber onde estou errando.

Comment: Você está dando `replace` no `Fragment`, mas você tem que fazer `replace` em um `FrameLayout`, como demonstrado [aqui nesse exemplo](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Como citei no comentário, "Você está dando `replace` no `Fragment`, mas você tem que fazer `replace` em um `FrameLayout`". Na verdade o `replace` não troca o elemento e sim o conteúdo do elemento. Seria algo assim adaptando seu exemplo:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnFrag1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fragment 1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnFrag2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fragment 2"/>
</LinearLayout>

<!-- Troque de LinearLayout para FrameLayout -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentPlace"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.example.dideconto.exemplofragmentsimples.Fragmento2"></fragment>
</FrameLayout>
```

No click do botão, ao invés de dar `replace` no `Fragment` de `replace` no conteúdo do `FrameLayout`:

```
Fragmento1 f1 = new Fragmento1();
FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
// troque o replace do Fragment  "fragmentPlace" para o FrameLayout "fragmentContainer"
transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer,f1);
transaction.commit();
```

> Obs: Não testei, então pode haver alguns erros de sintaxe, mas a ideia é basicamente essa.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Mas tenho apenas uma dúvida, o fragmento no XML serve apenas para que a app comece com um conteúdo?

Comment: @user3010958, sim! Mas eu não costumo utilizar em minhas aplicação, seto o `Fragment` via código ao iniciar a `Activity`. deixando no XML o `FrameLayout` vazio. Mas isso é maneira de implementação. =)

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado! Realmente ajudou bastante. Tem algum link para entender o pq do FrameLayout e não os outros tipos do layout?

Comment: @user3010958, acredito que outros elementos que aceitem elementos filhos (_child_), também possam ser utilizados, apesar de em todos os matérias oficiais que já vi, sempre é utilizado `FrameLayout` como _conteiner_ dos _fragments_, como por exemplo [nesse material](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html#AddAtRuntime).